# Is a widget or an iframe possible to add onto Google Slides?

Tags: html, iframe, google-slides

Is there a possible way to insert an html widget to google slides, and how? I'm trying to make a functional days, hours, seconds countdown timer. Is there an add on extension or is it possible to make an add on? I looked at all of those and found nothing, I had a look at apps script but that went nowhere because I don't even know how it works or how to "deploy" even if i could find a stable code.

I don't know what the hell i'm doing.
I tried apps script but it's probably not even for what I want.
I looked on the google add ons.
**I'm completely lost to the point where i'm asking for help**